# How to loop over queries and page results?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to scrape the results of three different queries from a fixed URL where I iterate on the result number (25 per page). For each query, I want the iteration to stop as it reaches a certain number.

So far, I got the code to stop at the desired result number, but it resumes at the same query instead of jumping to the next. I tried "break", "pass" and "continue". What am I doing wrong?

This  is my code so far:

```
for query in queries:
  while n<580:
    url = urlbase+query+period+str(n)
    print(url)
    r = requests.get(url)
    html = parser.fromstring(r.text)
    print(html)
    if n > 575:
      n=1
      continue
    else: 
      n=n+25
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for query in queries:
    for n in range(0, 580, 25): # iterate from 0 to 580 and step 25 each iteration.
        url = urlbase+query+period+str(n)
        print(url)
        r = requests.get(url)
        html = parser.fromstring(r.text)
        print(html)
```